# Too many tags on a question?

Tags: discussion, tags

prompted by someone else's 30 day adventure in answering Stack Overflow questions, I tried my hand at answering some of the unanswered questions for the angularjs tag.

What I found is that some of the questions aren't specific to angularjs though they're tagged with it. They're also tagged with the names of other packages being used by the user (such as nodejs or karma or whatever) but again, those tags aren't specific to their question.

Is there a nice way to deal with this other than editing and removing the tags? Seeing over 14000 unanswered questions is daunting to try and go through but I suspect many of those questions are just tagged incorrectly.

1. how do I deal with questions that have too many tags or too broad tags?
2. is there a nice way to encourage more specific tagging or fewer but more specific tags?

Comment: It sounds like you have a slightly different definition of "tagged correctly" than what most other users have. Typically, if there's *any* relation, you add the tag. Tags are also used to indicate what environment the OP is having trouble on even if it isn't specific to that environment. So it seems like you're looking for a behavior change in the users rather than to "correct" the millions of "mistagged" questions.

Comment: @Mysticial ohh ok, that kinda makes sense. I usually just leave the environment in the question rather than as a tag

Comment: Often times the OP doesn't know if the environment has anything to do with a question. So a Java syntax error can get tagged as Java/Android because the OP doesn't know (or incorrectly assumes) that Android has to do with it.

Comment: @Mysticial If you know that a tag doesn't have any relationship with the question, The Right Thing To Do™ is remove it.